# How to wait till HttpURLConnection completes?

Tags: java, http-post, synchronous, httpconnection

If I upload 100K file to certain url of my service, wget takes ~20 seconds to complete:

```
wget --quiet --post-file data.txt --output-document - --header "Content-Type: text/csv" http://localhost:8080/ingest
```

But if I do it like this in java, strangely this happens immediately:

```
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/csv;charset=UTF-8");
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println("code=" + con.getResponseCode());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
```

so my guess is that actually this code is not waiting for data to be submitted, but is doing this in background. How can I force it to block until actual data transfer is finished?

Comment: `outputStream.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));` are you sure that `str` is containing `100K` of data?

Comment: I think he's saying the opposite, that Java does its job quicker.  I dunno why except either luck or wget doesn't have some optimization that Java does.

Comment: no, appeding 100k to stringbuffer is very fast + my response is empty, i am sending 100K

Comment: yeah i realized i read the question wrong and deleted my comment

Comment: BTW, 20 seconds for 100K is really slow

Comment: 20 seconds is because service is processing data, i need to wait

Comment: str contains 100k data, correct

Comment: The implementation of Java's HttpURLConnection is a little stupid and might be just skipping parts of protocol that wget is actually trying to deal with.  That would be my guess.  Have  you tried taking a packet trace?

Comment: could you debug your service when it's getting the file? what's happening there?

Comment: I randomly stuck to very similar issue on Java 17 (Amazon Corretto). I had my debugger enabled and `connection.getResponseCode()` was -1. Nginx was showing 201 response, and the service response time is quite quick.
I started to fiddle with `connection.connect()`, it helped, though I was quite sure output buffer is calling connect internally. To make a sanity check, I rolled back, and that time issue did not happen. Rather weird. Might be one of those Schrödinger bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code *should* be waiting for the response to complete.  The `con.getResponseCode()` call will not (cannot!) return until the server has at least responded with the HTTP reply header containing the response code.

It may be that the server is sending the HTTP reply header before it has finished reading the data that the client has posted.  That would be a mistake.  (If the server sends the response too soon, it can't set the response code correctly!)

It is also possible that the server response is not a 2xx response, and there are server error messages / diagnostics on the error stream rather than the input stream.  (Read the javadocs on `getInputStream` versus `getErrorStream`.)

So the most likely reason that is not blocking for ~20 seconds is because the request has failed ... and this is not being reported properly, due to server or client-side implementation issues.

---

**UPDATE** - It turns out that the real issues was that "curl" was behaving strangely on some platforms, probably due to network config issues.

Comment: In that case, you need to start investigating on the server side to see why the request is (apparently) being handled differently.

Comment: HI, your reply to my question is technically correct, some more details are in my second question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474727/wget-behaves-differently-on-cygwin-and-centos